# How to login on tfs server on Azure with tf command line

Tags: tfs, tf-cli, azure-devops

we try to connect us on TFS with tf command line.

Everything working fine when we are connected, but when we try to connect to TFS server that doesn't work. We received a message prompt who ask us credentials, if we log in the prompt, everything will work fine after. But if we try to connect with the command line bellow we always received the message "You are not authorized to access TFS server".

I need to precise that we are using TFS in Azure and we try to sign-in with windows live account.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>tf workspace /server:https://xxx.TFSURL.com /new site
TfsWorskpace -login:xxx@xxxx.com,password
TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://xxx.TFSURL.com/.
TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://xxx.TFSURL.com/.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable basic authentication support on your TFS preview account.

Have a look at the release notes for the [27-Aug-2012](http://tfspreview.com/en-us/home/news/2012/aug-27/) update to TFS Preview for a step-by-step explanation on how to set it up.